# Android Studio Error: "Wifi direct has stopped"

Tags: android

The following code is giving an error when it is run on a tablet.
I am not sure if I am missing anything.

Please help me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sahgal.robotcontrolapp"
    android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<!-- Google Play filtering --> 
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Used for transferring files  after a successful connection -->
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".FileTransferService" />

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.0 and later only support wifi direct. However, some of 4.x devices does not support it because of their wifi driver.

To overcome this problem you need to check your device is supportable with wifi direct or not. For checking it use this code:

```
objManager.discoverPeers(objChannel, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        //onSuccess
    }
    @Override
    public void onFailure(int reason) {
        //onFailure
    }
});
```